# Avoid Chat Window from popping up when I send a chat message from an external jabber client

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-talk, xmpp

I use Google Talk from a different external client (pidgin). Whenever I sent a message from there, it also pops up within my browser on my Gmail tab.

Is there a way to avoid that?

I don't mind getting the popup when I receive messages, but when I am the one sending them it's redundant and annoying.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't a way to prevent only the redundant notifications and keeping the initial notification for incoming messages.

What you could do is shut chat off in your Gmail window by going to `Settings` > `Chat` > `Chat off`

This *should* allow you to chat using an external product without the native Gmail windows opening up. The downside is that obviously if you are not currently on Pidgin then you'll have to re-enable chat.